# Maclaurin serie of $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Help me finding the Maclaurin serie of
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)} $$
in the easiest way (if there is one which you do not have to calculate a lot of derivatives) possible, please.

Comment: Partial fractions. No derivative needed.

Comment: HINT: Break $f(x)$ into partial fractions, and use the fact that

$$\frac1{1-u}=\sum_{n\ge 0}u^n\;.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a easier method: Let $$\frac 1{(1-x)(1-2x)} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j x^j$$. Multiplying both sides of the equation by the denominator $(1-x)(1-2x)$ allows you to setup a linear recurrence relation(very easy to solve) for the coefficients $(a_j)_{j=0}^\infty$, and the initial condition can be found by plugging in $x=0$.

Comment: I would not upvote this answer since it is actually much more complicated than the answers that mention or show partial fractions.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {1}{(1-x)(1-2 x)}=\frac {2}{1-2 x}-\frac {1}{1- x}$. Is this enough? This is what 2 prior comments mean by partial fractions.

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Comment: Just checking, now I just gotta get the power serie of each and calculate the subtraction, right?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$-\frac{1}{8}f\bigg(\frac{1}{4}t+\frac{3}{4}\bigg)=\frac{1}{1-t^2} $$
using this hint we get
$$-\frac{1}{8}f\bigg(\frac{1}{4}t+\frac{3}{4}\bigg)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{t^{2k}}$$
converging for $|t|<1$ and $t\not=0$
by taking $t=4x-3$ we arrive at
$$f(x)=-8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{(4x-3)}^{2k}}$$
converging for $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$ and $x\not=\frac{3}{4}$